# Using '$' instead of 'jQuery' in WordPress

Tags: jquery, javascript

jQuery included with WordPress is in [compatibility mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). To avoid conflicts with other libraries we can not use the '$' shortcut for 'jQuery'.

To use the '$' sign we use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color':'white'});
});
```

This works. But my question is how to do the same with window load. I have been facing this problem since last few projects. So, thought better to make the concept clear.

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
   $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color':'white'});
});
```

With this I get an error that says : "$ is not a function". So, I am unable to use $ inside of the window.load code block.

So, can anyone help how I can use the $ shortcut inside window.load?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a self invoking anonymous function that passes the jQuery object will do the trick:

```
(function($){ 
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color':'white'});
   });
})(jQuery); //Passing the jQuery object as a first argument
```

Comment: Off-topic note: strictly speaking, this function isn't *self-invoking* - it doesn't invoke itself, it's *you* invoking it immediately after defining. [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) is a better name IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This is because window [load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is different than Jquery [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Note also this function can take multiple parameters.

```
(function(wordpress, $){ 
   $(window).load(function(){
     var emoji = wordpress.emoji; 
     // do somehting with emoji ;)
     console.log(emoji);
     $('body').css({'background': 'black', 'color':'white'});
   });
})(wp, jQuery);
```